# Ordering int values orders 11,12,13 before 2

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In my Sql table the index primary key is an integer (1,2,3,...)
I have an Entity query like this :

```
                var pagedQAs = getAllQAs
                .Where(qa => qa.Show)
                .OrderByDescending(qa => qa.Code)
                .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                .Select(QAViewModels.Set)
                .ToList();
```

And the result sorted list is like this:

```
1
11
12
...
2
21
22
...
3
31
32
...
```

What should be right to show correct ordered numbers?

**Edit**>>>

**Table in sql** :
[Table in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UECQK.jpg)

The project is Model First Not Code First

**The model :**

```
public class QAViewModels
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string InquirerName { get; set; }
    public string InquirerEmail { get; set; }
    public int VisitCounts { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Respondent { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RespondDate { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string AnswerSummary { get; set; }

    public virtual BaseMember BaseMember { get; set; }

    public static QAViewModels Set(QuestionAnswer qa)
    {
        return new QAViewModels
        {
            Code = qa.Code,
            Question = qa.Question,
            InquirerName = qa.InquirerName,
            InquirerEmail = qa.InquirerEmail,
            VisitCounts = qa.VisitCounts,
            Respondent = qa.Respondent,
            RespondDate = qa.RespondDate,
            Answer = qa.Answer,
            AnswerSummary = qa.AnswerSummary,

            BaseMember = qa.BaseMember
        };
    }
}
```

All types are based on SQL table fileds data type

**The Store :**

```
        public List<QAViewModels> GetAllRawPaged(int page, int pageSize, out int count)
    {
        var getAllQAs = Tools.DataModel.QuestionAnswers;

        count = getAllQAs.Count();
            var pagedQAs = getAllQAs
                .Where(qa => qa.Show)
                .OrderByDescending(qa => qa.Code)
                .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                .Select(QAViewModels.Set)
                .ToList();

            return pagedQAs;
    }
```

Actions and queries on data stored in QAStore

**The Controller :**

```
        public ActionResult CM_QAs()
    {
        QAStore qas = new QAStore();

        int count = 0;

        LabelStore ls = new LabelStore();

        List<TagsViewsModel> tags = ls.GetAllTags();

        List<QAViewModels> allQAs = qas.GetAllRawPaged(1, 100, out count);

        return View(allQAs);
    }
```

Get all QuestionAnswers and pass to view

**The View :**

```
@model List<wrrc.Models.QAViewModels>

<div>
    @foreach (var qa in Model)
        {
        <div>
        <span>
            <span>Question Number 
            @Tools.ConvertNumerals(Convert.ToString(qa.Code))
            </span>
        </span>
        <div>@Html.Raw(qa.Question)</div>
        <div>@Tools.TruncateAtWord(qa.Answer, 500)))</div>
        <a href="@Url.Action("SingleQA", "QA" >Full Description</a>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: What is the data type of Code column?

Comment: Quite clearly its sorting these as text. Why or how it's working with text rather than the integers you claim cannot be discovered by us from so little code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Code column data type is integer

Comment: The result shown doesn't seem to be produced by the shown query (the order is not descending by any means). Can we see the generated SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the `Code` as int;

```
var pagedQAs = getAllQAs
    .Where(qa => qa.Show)
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(qa => int.Parse(qa.Code))
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .Select(QAViewModels.Set)
    .ToList();
```

Also, It could be better to prevent possible null values or incorrect strings to parse integer;

```
int val = 0;
var pagedQAs = getAllQAs
    .Where(qa => qa.Show)
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(qa => int.TryParse(qa.Code,out val) ? val : Int32.MaxValue)
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .Select(QAViewModels.Set)
    .ToList();
```

Also, with this query you should perform `order/skip/take` actions on the client side. `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse` can't be translated to sql query in IQueryable form. So, if you have a chance to modify `Code` column as `int` in the database, it could be better solution.

Comment: You've changed it so that all results will be fetched by the client, sorted, then paged. The original (probably) did the paging server-side. Also, we don't know if all codes are representations of integers, and if not, how the other codes should be sorted.

Comment: Yes, i know it. But is there a way to cast string to int for linq to entities ?

Comment: @Rainman Thanks but int.TryParse gets string as its argument, qa.Code is an integer

Comment: I think it is not possible. What is the property type in the entity ?

Comment: @Mehdi Then your property type does not match your database column's type. Change one to match the other.

Comment: @hvd, SqlFunctions.StringConvert it is converting numeric to string. Not string to numeric.

Comment: @Rainman Drat, sorry, you're right, that's the wrong one here. For the other way around, I don't think there's something in `SqlFunctions` specifically. I'm pretty sure the conversion is supported but am not so sure off of the top of my head which syntax can be used to get it.